# Placing several pictures in one line, but with linebreak

Tags: graphics, line-breaking, subfloats

I am trying to plot several pictures in one line, but only two per line and then the next two in the next line. And I want it all to be in one Figure so that I have only one caption. I can place several pictures in a row, but without linebreak.

```
\begin{figure}[H]
  \begin{center}
    \mbox{
      \subfigure[title1]{\scalebox{0.3}{\includegraphics{..path...}}}\qquad 
      \subfigure[title2]{\scalebox{0.3}{\includegraphics{...path2...}}} \linebreak
      \subfigure[title3]{\scalebox{0.3}{\includegraphics{...path3...}}}\qquad 
      \subfigure[title3]{\scalebox{0.3}{\includegraphics{...path4...}}}
      }
    \caption{my caption}
    \label{fig:myfigures}
  \end{center}
\end{figure}
```

The `\linebreak` above does not work. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove `\mbox` the only thing it is doing is preventing the linebreak.